# Angular 5 ngForm prefilled with value="{{variable}}" is undefined on submit

Tags: forms, angular5

I use the same form to create and update my data. When i select a record to update, it fills the form correctly but if I submit, the values are undefined

```
<form (ngSubmit)="create(addMountForm)" #addMountForm="ngForm" ngNativeValidate> 
<div class="form-row" style="margin: 0 auto;">
  <div class="form-group col-md-2">
    <label for="name">Name(*)</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="name" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Countdown-Name" required value="{{current_name}}">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-2">
    <label for="datepicker">Datum(*)</label>
    <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="datepicker" name="datepicker" id="datepicker" placeholder="Datum" required value="{{current_timestamp * 1000 | date: 'yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm'}}">
  </div>
</div>
```

The variables are defined like this:

```
  current_name:string;
  current_timestamp:number;
```

The submitted form contains the values like this:

```
value:
    name: undefiend
    datepicker: undefiend
```